# Randomly insert 1 of 3 declared variables

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, random, plpgsql

I have three variables that are declared and have an integer value assigned to them.

I am trying to randomly assign the integer value to a field in an `UPDATE` statement, but get an error.

This is statement I am trying to execute:

```
FOR user_record IN (SELECT * FROM users_to_add) LOOP
    UPDATE 
        customer."user"
    SET
        primary_site_id  = ({site_GRO, site_WHS, site_SHR}[])[ceil(random()*3)],
    WHERE
        userid = (SELECT userID FROM customer.user
                  WHERE emailaddress=user_record.email_address);           
END LOOP;
```

I am getting:

> ```
> SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
> ```

This same format works if the value being randomly selected is a string but since these are variables, the inside curly brackets can't be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres and a complete function / `DO` statement to make this easier. Are `site_GRO`, `site_WHS`, and `site_SHR` supposed to be separate variables or come from `customer."user"`?

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) instead of the (invalid) array literal.

```
(ARRAY[site_GRO, site_WHS, site_SHR])[ceil(random()*3)]
```

**However**, a set-based solution is typically more efficient than looping:

```
UPDATE customer."user" u
SET    primary_site_id  = CASE trunc(random()*3)::int
                             WHEN 0 THEN site_gro  -- your variables here
                             WHEN 1 THEN site_whs
                             WHEN 2 THEN site_shr
                           END
FROM   users_to_add ua
WHERE  u.userid = ua.email_address;
```

Should achieve the same. Works *inside* a PL/pgSQL block or as standalone SQL DML command (then you need to interpolate variable values yourself).

A single multi-row `UPDATE` is *much* cheaper than many updates in a loop.

[`trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) is slightly more correct than `ceil()`, as [random()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) returns a value in the domain `[0,1)` (`1` excluded). It's also faster.

And a `CASE` construct is substantially faster than building an array just to extract a single element from it.

Asides:

Avoid reserved words like `user` as identifiers. Always requires double-quoting, and can lead to confusing errors when forgotten.
Also avoid random capitalization in identifiers. This goes for SQL as well as for PL/pgSQL. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try splitting the index and array out into their own vars?

```
FOR user_record IN (SELECT * FROM users_to_add) LOOP
  a := ARRAY[site_GRO, site_WHS, site_SHR];
  i := ceil(random()*3);
  UPDATE 
    customer."user"
  SET
    primary_site_id  = a[i]
  WHERE
    userid = (SELECT userID FROM customer.user WHERE emailaddress=user_record.email_address);        
END LOOP;
```